# Azure Logic App SQL ODATA Filter on Date

Tags: azure, odata, azure-logic-apps

I'm creating a new Logic App that reads a table where `DateCreated < ADDDAYS(-60,GETDATE())` and updates an `Archived` bit to `1`.

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement that filter as part of the ODATA query.

Here's what I'm trying so far:
`DateCreated lt addDays(utcNow(),-60)`

However, I get `"An unknown function with name 'utcnow' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed.\r\n     inner exception: An unknown function with name 'utcnow' was found. This may also be a function import or a key lookup on a navigation property, which is not allowed."`

How can I filter on a dynamic date in the filer?

Answer (score 2):

> However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to implement that filter as part of the ODATA query.

I suppose you mean on the ODATA Query on the SQL Connector?

Can you try the following:

DateCreated lt @{addDays(utcNow(),-60)}

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for the tip.  I did try that, and now I'm getting 
Body
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Mashup Expression using supplied values.\r\n     inner exception: We cannot apply operator < to types DateTimeZone and DateTime.",
  "source": "127.0.0.1"
}

Comment: Can you try DateCreated le @{addDays(utcNow(),-60)}

Comment: Yep, same error :(.  For what it's worth, DateCreated is a nullable DateTime in the db

Comment: Is the DateCreated in your table a datetime or datetimeoffset? Try casting the DateCreated as a datetime. Looks like it is being read as a DateTimeZone type instead of a DateTime, so the comparison can not occur.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  How do I cast it as a datetime?  I'm trying to figure that out but not making progress

Comment: I tried DateCreated lt '@{addDays(utcNow(),-60)}'. But when I run the query on the SQL Server, I got a date format error. How to format the date ?

Comment: formatDateTime('2015-03-15T13:27:36Z', 'o'). Both single format specifiers as custom format specifiers are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the previous answer, you should try the same command :

```
DateCreated lt @{addDays(utcNow(),-60)}
```

But also, you must ensure that your data type, on the SQL side, must be a datetimeoffset.

Three solutions to do this :

- Change the type of your field in your table,
- Create a view and cast the field DateCreated to DATETIMEOFFSET
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[myview] AS
  SELECT MyFields, ..., CAST(DateCreated AS DATETIMEOFFSET) AS DateCreated
  FROM MyTable
- Create a store procedure with a DATETIMEOFFSET parameter, and convert the parameter to a DATETIME

If you can not change your SQL code, this piece of code is the solution :

```
year(DateCreated) lt year(@{addDays(utcNow(),-60)}) or (
    year(DateCreated) eq year(@{addDays(utcNow(),-60)}) and (
            month(DateCreated) lt month(@{addDays(utcNow(),-60)} or (
                month(DateCreated) eq month(@{addDays(utcNow(),-60)}
                ... <same thing for other date parts>
        )
    )
)
```

You have to compare each part of your date :

> This is an interesting issue that sometimes shows up when dates,
>   times, datetimes, and specific time zone come into play. Comparing a
>   DateTimeZone to a date is problematic, because it might be less in
>   arithmetic terms but only if the time zone matches... without that
>   critical piece of information, these data types cannot be compared.
>
> One alternative is to use the standard OData functions to retrieve
>   parts of the data type. For example:
>
> $filter = year(release_date) lt year(dtz)
>
> Of course, you must be carful to ensure that you are implementing the
>   correct logic with respect to timezone- but you are probably aware of
>   that.

OData Reference :
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

Comment: The SQL is out of my control.  If I could cast to datetimeoffset in the Logic App, that would work for me, but I can't change the SQL side

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Just asked to Microsoft.

Comment: Works for me.  Can you post back here when/if they respond?