# Azure Logic App, SQL Get rows with DateTime comparison

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-logic-apps

In an Azure Logic App, I'm attempting to use the SQL Server "Get rows" action, using an On-premises Data Gateway with a simple ODATA Filter Query:

```
mdate gt 2018-05-07T07:15:12Z
```

mdate, in this case, is a DateTime field.

This is returning with HttpCode 502, "Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server". Is there a fix, workaround, or at least a reason I'm seeing this issue?

Comment: Could you please add more details ? Is it an azure sql database ? what is the type of the mdate field: `date, datetime,datetimeoffset` ?

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. I've updated my question with the relevant info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logic Apps ODATA Filter works well with datetimeoffset types but not with datetime types.

Either you change the data type to datetimeoffset or have a complex ODATA filter to compare each part of the datetime e.g.

```
year(mdate) gt year(2018-05-07T07:15:12Z) and 
month(mdate) gt month(2018-05-07T07:15:12Z) and 
day(mdate) gt day(2018-05-07T07:15:12Z) and so on...
```

You can find a detailed discussion on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143562/azure-logic-app-sql-odata-filter-on-date).

HTH

Comment: That's what I found, as well, Paco. Thanks for the verification.